# Retrieve go-swagger annotation from swagger.json

Tags: go, swagger

I am learning to generate swagger.json from go-swagger generator, but I have not found any complete example (with meta, and all methods).

Is there any way to retrieve the go-swagger annotation back from the generated JSON?

Comment: One of the packages in go-swagger vendor directory is go-openapi and they have an Unmarshal method for Swagger; https://godoc.org/github.com/go-openapi/spec#Swagger.UnmarshalJSON